# SSRS Highlight sentence in a cell

Tags: reporting-services, highlight

Please advise how to highlight sentence (change color to red) in a cell that is bounded by $ sign? For example: some text here that needs to be $hightlighted because$ business rules

From the above sentence font for "highlighted because" must be changed to red and $ sign must be removed.

Thank you

Comment: What tools are you using to edit the reports? (VStudio 2015?) Are you familiar/comfortable-with formulas in SSRS?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use HTML formatting in the text box. Highlight the Expression and select the Placeholder Properties.

[image]

Then set the Markup Type to HTML.

[image]

Add some logic to replace the dollar signs with HTML tags. This only works if there's one highlight per sentence, though - if there can be multiple ones, you'd need some VB for more advanced logic.

```
=LEFT(Parameters!TEXT.Value, InStr(Parameters!TEXT.Value, "$") - 1) & 
    "<font color = 'red'>" & 
    MID(Parameters!TEXT.Value, InStr(Parameters!TEXT.Value, "$") + 1, 
        InStrRev(Parameters!TEXT.Value, "$") - InStr(Parameters!TEXT.Value, "$") - 1 ) &  
    "</font>" & 
    MID(Parameters!TEXT.Value, InStrRev(Parameters!TEXT.Value, "$") + 1, LEN(Parameters!TEXT.Value) )
```

And the result is:

[image: Result]

I used a parameter instead of a field, so you'd need to change the parameters to your field name.